# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers

I have recently installed Ubuntu on an external drive and as I was using it yesterday it was working fine. Today when I logged in I could not connect to the WiFi. I am getting this error, No Wi-Fi Adapter found.
I have tried following other online solutions but I cannot seem to find the right adapter for my controller.
My network controller is as follows; **Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi**
When I run my laptop in the primary OS (Windows) I can connect to WiFi but on booting with Linux, I cannot

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 This solved my problem. Thank you so much. Disabling the "Fast Startup" option just did the trick